# Lightbox stacking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, featherlight.js

Just wondering, is it possible to open a lightbox in an already opened lightbox? 
I'm currently using Featherlight to open a lightbox, and I want to open a featherlight gallery lightbox from within that lightbox.
(Does that make sense? XD )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `featherlight`s can be nested (no limit).